# Sorting datetime.datetime 2d array

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following 2D array, the date format is %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S :

```
[['second comment test', datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 15, 49, 40), 's']
['this comment originated in service now', datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 14, 45), 's']
['this is a longer description used for testing', datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 14, 13, 49), 'z']]
```

I noticed that if one of the logs for time is at exactly a minute for example **2018-08-22 14:45:00** Meaning that it ends in 00 it wont log the seconds. So how can I order this array by date?

Comment: `arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])` will sort by the second element in each list if your list is named `arr`. This will sort in-place.

Comment: What exactly is this? A numpy array or a Series? Or just a Python list?

Comment: `datetime` objects are stored internally as integers. Not sure why you think you have `date format is %Y....`. As such, sorting will work regardless of the seconds value being 0.

Comment: I agree with @jpp . You'll need a reproducible example for this

Comment: I am initializaing as this : all_comments = [] 
@DietrichEpp I just tried that and it says "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you have is a list, as mentioned by @DietrichEpp, you can simply sort this array by:

```
list_ = [
    ['second comment test', datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 15, 49, 40), 's'],
    ['this comment originated in service now', datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 14, 45), 's'],
    ['this is a longer description used for testing', datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 14, 13, 49), 'z'],]
list_.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: had to make some minor changes, but this is the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: @MarioLanda, I'm glad to know it was useful.